# average of dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to create a function that takes a dictionary containing the scores of different rounds as an argument. The function returns the average score for all rounds.

Here's an example of how the function should work:

```py
>>> find_average({'round 1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'round 2': [3, 4, 2, 7], 'round 3': [2, 7, 5, 6]})
4.8
```

I tried this:

```
def find_average(dictionary):
    average = sum(dictionary.values())/len(dictionary)
    return average
```

But I received an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

What should I do?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is obviously a list and you can't add it with an integer

Comment: How did you get the value `4.8`?

Comment: isn't avg is 3.83 ?

Comment: @RahulKP sorry my bad, took the average from a different example given, it should be 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the average of each value in the dictionary and find the average of that list.

```
def find_average(dictionary):
    sums = [sum(lst)/len(lst) for lst in dictionary.values()]
    return sum(sums)/len(sums)
```

The result will be `3.8333333333333335` but you can round the result like this `round(sum(sums)/len(sums), 1)` which gives you `3.8`

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
d = {'round 1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'round 2': [3, 4, 2, 7], 'round 3': [2, 7, 5, 6]}
sum(chain(*d.values()))/len(list(chain(*d.values())))

#output : 3.8333333333333335
```

Answer (score 0):

You were summing the dictionary values which were each one is a list, and dividing by the length of keys which is incorrect.

```py
print(sum(dictionary.values()))
""" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import user_code
  File "/tmp/user_code.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(find_average({'round 1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'round 2': [3, 4, 2, 7], 'round 3': [2, 7, 5, 6]}))
  File "/tmp/user_code.py", line 6, in find_average
    print(sum(dictionary.values()))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

"""
```

The reason why the previous code fails, is because `sum` operates on lists,  **NOT** on list of lists.

The following run returns the correct answer:

```py
def find_average(dictionary):
    s = 0
    c = 0
    for i in dictionary.values():
        s += sum(list(i))
        c += len(list(i))
    return s/c;
find_average({'round 1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'round 2': [3, 4, 2, 7], 'round 3': [2, 7, 5, 6]})) #  3.8333333333333335
```